# fields value as field name in view

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables and I need to create a view.

The tables are as follows:

```
pc_assign(table_name)
  username    pc_name         (fields name)
  nitu        pc1

pc_configuration(table_name)
   hw_serial_no    pc_name       (fields name)
   check           pc_1

hw_property(table_name)
   hardware_name   hw_serial_no    property        value        (fields name)
   cpu             cpu123          speed(GHz)      2.0
   RAM             ram234          size(GB)        4
   HDD             h454            size(GB)        80
   Monitor         moni567         screen(inches)  12

pc_config_view(view_name)
   username    pc_name   CPU(GHz)    RAM(GB) HDD(GB) Monitor     (fields name)
   nitu        pc_1       2.0          4       80      12
```

I wanted something like following:-
if hw_property.hardware_name= `cpu`
then a value get enter in 
pc_config_view.CPU(GHz)=hw_property.value
 when 
pc_configuration.hw_serial_no=hw_property.hw_serial_no.

I am able to take `username` and `pc_name` from above first 2 tables. But is it possible to fill other columns of the view from table 3.  I am confused here.

One more thing: I am not using any language here, I want to do this with SQL only.

Comment: Could you post here what you have tried? And what is that other field you want from the 3rd table in the view.

Comment: @sathishD: I tried to create a view that is pc_conf_view in which all information about 1 pc can be taken

Comment: @SathisD: I posted more information in question. Please check is it enough to understand the question or not. Please let me know

Comment: Your problem is called "pivoting" -- that is, making columns from rows. Suggestion: read about pivoting.

Comment: @OllieJones: kindly suggest any url relevant to pivoting???